# How can I use the Google App Engine Datastore from a Scala app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scala

I'm writing a Scala app, to be deployed on the Google App Engine. I've tried following the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html) for using entities in the datastore, but the code won't compile.

```
import java.util.Date; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity; 
// ... 
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
```

This gives me an error on the last line, which says:

```
"Expected class or object definition"
```

Is there different code I should be using because I'm writing in Scala?

Comment: Can you show us the compilation errors you get?

Comment: `import java.util.Date;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

// ...
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();`

This gives me an error on the last line, which says: "Expected class or object definition"

Comment: Your problem is that you're creating objects outside of a class definition... You can't just randomly write "DatastoreService datastore = ..." outside of a method.

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu You should post that as an answer (because it is one). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is different code that you should be writing in Scala.

For example, to create an integer object with the value 42 you would write:

```
var theNum = 42
```

or perhaps

```
val theNum = 42
```

Note that your long statement does not include either `var` or `val`.

Also, you can leave off a lot of the stuff that you write in Java. I expect that it will work if your simply write:

```
val datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService
```

The Scala compiler will infer that it is a DataStoreService. Just a waste of time to write that except in function/method definitions. The compiler will also infer the semicolons at the end of most lines. I'm not sure about whether or not the compiler will infer `()` in the method call but why not try it and see if it does. This is a new language and you need to get used to the idea of writing things differently.